# Change iteration rate on itertools

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have this iteration count using iter tools:

```py
for i in itertools.count(start=2**68):
```

And I want it to bump up an exponent every time (68,69,70,71,...). Is there support for this in itertools? I have looked at the step option on the itertools documentation, but don't see any way to change by exponential type only float, integer.

Comment: You would need to loop over the exponents, and use `2**i` in the body of the loop.

Comment: @jasonharper Sorry I am not understanding what you mean by, loop over the exponents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not a function specially made for that, but it's very easy to make what you want from basic components:

```py
for i in map(lambda i: 2**i, itertools.count(start=68)):
```

Incidentally, one of the comments says `map(lambda...)` is an antipattern, and should instead be replaced with generator expressions. Here is how to do in case you wonder.

```py
for i in (2**i for i in itertools.count(start=68)):
```

Comment: Antipattern meaning it generates lag or what is exactly the downside of map and lambda if you don't mind explaining

Comment: it isn't an anti-pattern, it's mostly a stylistic thing

Comment: I didn't say it is an anti-pattern (it **is** my answer...), I said somebody in the comments (of the other answer) said it was.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Can you name even a single advantage over generator expressions? It's slower, longer code, and doesn't support unpacking like genexps do.

Comment: @Thornily, `lambda` can be difficult to debug and it is typically less performant than using stdlib packages like `operator`, `functools`, etc. Simple `lambda`S are less likely to have these issues but still are a code smell. I think in this, specific case that any negative impact will be minimal.

Answer (score 3):

Use `itertools.count` for the exponent, and do the exponentiation separately:

```
for exponent in itertools.count(start=68):
    i = 2 ** exponent
    print(i)
```

Comment: This is another great answer, but I love the use of map and lambda in @BlackBeans answer.

Comment: Yes. It took me a moment to remember that Python's `map` is a generator, so it works with a generator argument.

Comment: @Thornily map+lambda is an antipattern one shouldn't love.

Comment: @KellyBundy That's usually true when the better alternative is a list comprehension. But that's not the case here because `itertools.count()` is an infinite generator.

Comment: @KellyBundy What? When exactly should `lambda` be used if not specifically when fed to higher order functions for which you don't want to give a name to the parameter?

Comment: @Barmar You don't know generator expressions?

Comment: @KellyBundy I realized that's what you meant as soon as I hit Enter.

Comment: @BlackBeans lambda is good in plenty of situations, but not in map.

Comment: @KellyBundy Whatever, I edited my answer to provide the generator expression way. Still, I'm a bit skeptical about `map(lambda...)` being an anti-pattern...

Comment: And if you're using it as the control of a `for` loop, there's really no benefit over putting the expontiation as the first line of the loop body, as I did. It saves one line but makes it a little more complex.

Comment: @Barmar it's much more readable (using a builtin way of doing things instead of by hand is usually more readable), and easier to maintain.

Comment: `for i in (... for ...)` just looks kind of redundant to me.

Answer (score 1):

To piggyback on the great answers by Barmar and Blackbeans, `map` may be used without `lambda` to achieve a solution.

```py
import itertools
import functools
import math
pow_base2 = functools.partial(math.pow, 2)
for i in map(pow_base2, itertools.count(start=68)):
    print(i)
```

Or if you don't want to deal with `float`S (thanks Kelly Bundy for the suggestion).

```py
import itertools
import functools
pow_base2 = functools.partial(pow, 2)
for i in map(pow_base2, itertools.count(start=68)):
    print(i)
```

Comment: @KellyBundy, no prob. Thank you for the suggestion. I think that `pow` is likely more appropriate than `math.pow` in this context.